# About SMS service from Amazon SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I want [Amazon SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/) to send SMS to cell phones. I checked the AWS document, it says

```
SMS notifications are currently supported for phone numbers in the     
United States. SMS messages can be sent only from topics created in the 
US East (N. Virginia) region. However, you can publish messages to 
topics that you create in the US East (N. Virginia) region from any 
other region.
```

But I don't know how to publish a message to the topics that I create in the US East region from US West which my aws nodes are located.

Googled a lot, but without luck. Does anybody here know how?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter where your code is running... even somewhere not part of AWS.  Most services, like SNS, have a [regional endpoint](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#sns_region) That you need to access, in order to connect with resources defined in that region.  That's what the AWS console is doing, behind the scenes.

If you are using an SDK or another library, rather than using your own code to directly communicate with the AWS services, then what you're looking for is how to change or set  the "region" or "endpoint" with the request or (likely) in the constructor.

You can only send requests "from any other region" in same sense that you can send requests from the Internet, generally.  You don't send them *through* the other region's SNS endpoint.  You connect directly to the target region.

Note, though, that the SNS SMS solution is of somewhat limited utility -- useful for notifications to groups of individuals who are expecting your notifications ("The nightly global batch process has completed, but errors were encountered.") but not so much for customer contact ("Your order has been shipped.") since the topic subscribers are not individually addressable... send to one, send to all... all who responded positively to the subscription confirmation message, that is.

Comment: Thanks Michael. My use case is very simple. I configure an AWS cloudwatch alarm. When the alarm happens, I need cloudwatch to send SMS to my phone. Because generally we can use the email gateway to to send SMS, but SNS topics need confirmation. The confirmation link is not clickable in SMS.  Can you tell me how I can do this operation?

Comment: For that application, it's great.  If you are doing it correctly, the confirmation will be a text message from short code 30304 asking you to reply "Yes `topic_name`."   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SMS-subscribe-to-topic.html

Comment: If you are still stuck on how to access the us-esst-1 region, I'll need to know your programming language and SDK version in order to point you in the right direction on setting the region, though all I'll be doing is consulting the appropriate documentation.

Comment: Thank you Michael for your patient explanation. But I still have problems. Here I elaborate my use case a little bit. I don't have customized code on this use case. I just let AWS cloudwatch to monitor the healthiness of an instance like when the instance is down, cloudwatch will send email to a predefined topic.

Comment: Now I want cloudwatch to send SMS instead of email. But the SMS feature is only available at US east region. This means that I can only create a topic that has SMS functionality at US east region. But the nodes I am monitoring is at US west region. So now comes the problem, I need cloudwatch that is monitoring node in US west region to send the alert to a topic that are defined at US east region.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample function that uses the [Node.js SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/sdk-for-javascript/) to send an SMS message from an AWS lambda function:

```js
module.exports.sendMessage = (event, context, cb) => {
  const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
  const sns = new AWS.SNS({ region: 'us-east-1' });
  const params = {
    Message: 'The text message body.',
    PhoneNumber: '+15555555555',
  };
  sns.publish(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      cb(null, { message: 'Error: ' + err, event });
    } else {
      // data has the following form:
      // var data = {
      //   ResponseMetadata: { RequestId: '12345678-1234-5678-1234-012345678901' },
      //   MessageId: '12345678-1234-5678-1234-012345678901'
      // };
      cb(null, { message: data.MessageId, event });
    }
  });
}
```

You can [read more about it here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html#publish-property) or adapt it to use [another SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/) according to your architecture.  Don't forget to setup the correct IAM permissions to allow for sending SNS messages for whatever will be running this.